# How to get data page by page and sort column

Tags: sql-server

How to create a SP, using which I can get  result page vise. I want to pass pageSize, pageNo, sortCol and direction into SP and want result based on this info. Can I handle this in SP's logic?

```
Table1 { First, Last, Location }

SP_GetAll(pageNo=3, pageSize=10, sortCol="First", direction="ASC")
```

Any new feature provided by SQL Server 2008 for this?

Comment: Nothing new in 2008 compared to 2005. Usual approach is to use `row_number()` and then select the records between 2 values. SQL Server 2011 has [OFFSET](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2011-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) though which makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find an inline table valued function (TVF) more suitable to this than a sproc. Reason being is the results can participate in other queries.

At the beginning of your select statement, include the following:

```
SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...
```

At the end of your select statement, put the following:

```
WHERE   (Table.rowNo BETWEEN (@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize + 1 
         AND @pageNumber * @pageSize)
```

If the data set is large, (or your query complex), consider spooling the results to a temp table and paging around the temp table.